# extends base in html flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html

this is home.html

```
{%extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
  {{ super() }}
  <style type="text/css">
    .important { color: #336699; }
  </style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Index</h1>
  <p class="important">
    Welcome on my awesome homepage.
  </p>
{% endblock %}
```

this is base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>{% block title %}Congo Confort{% endblock %}</title>
  <style>
    /* Navbar styles */
    nav {
      background-color: purple;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    nav a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 0 10px;
    }
    nav a:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    /* Page styles */
    body {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0;
    }
    /* Footer styles */
    footer {
      background-color: purple;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 48px;
      text-align: left;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    what is happening here
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2023 Congo Confort. All rights reserved.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

folder structure

main.py
website
|        |
static   templates
|
base.html
views.py
home.html
etc...

SO I have two problems, first it home.html does not extend base.html and also when I run my code, I get the error that it cannot find home.html

Comment: Are `home.html` and `base.html` on the same folder (`templates`)?

Comment: yes they are on the same folder

Comment: Just to make sure, your template folder needs to be called `templates` in order for flask's default templating to work.

Comment: yes my templating folder is called templates

Answer (score 1):

edit your home.html
from:

```
{%extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
<style type="text/css">
 .important { color: #336699; }
</style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>Index</h1>
 <p class="important">
  Welcome on my awesome homepage.
 </p>
{% endblock %}
```

to:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %} {% block body %}
<style type="text/css">
.important { color: #336699; }
</style>
<h1>Index</h1>
 <p class="important">
 Welcome on my awesome homepage.
</p>
```

{% endblock %}

Result (my example base is a bit different, but the goal is the same)
https://github.com/spawnmarvel/test/blob/main/extend_base.jpg

Comment: @raph mwanza please accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution :)